# puppetdb stringify structured facts like hashes

Tags: hash, puppet, stringify, facter

I have a Problem with puppetdb and my structured facts (hashes).

Hashes will stringified through my puppetdb.

```
Ubuntu 14.04
puppetserver     = 3.8.7
facter           = 2.4.4
puppetdb         = 2.3.8-1
```

In my puppet.conf on the clients and server i have included:

```
stringify_facts  = false
```

In my site.pp i have following entry:

```
  if is_hash($::os) {
    notify {'hash':}
    notify {$os['family']:}
    }

    if is_string($::os) {
    notify {'string':}
    notify {$os['family']:}
    }
```

If in my puppet.conf on the Server:

```
storeconfigs          = true
storeconfigs_backend  = puppetdb
```

and the puppetdb is running.

I get the following message on the Client puppetrun:

```
os is not a hash or Array when accesssing it with family.
```

If i changed my site.pp to only:

```
  if is_string($::os) {
    notify {'os is a string':}
  }
```

Then i get the message -> 'os is a string'

If i change the puppet.conf on my server to:

```
storeconfigs          = false
storeconfigs_backend  = puppetdb
```

then all is ok. os fact will identified as a hash.

Has anyone a idea?
Please help :)
Taner

Comment: I am assuming from `is_hash` that you are using `puppetlabs-stdlib`, correct? I thought intrinsic facts were not hashes in general with Facter < 3.0. Also, this probably has no effect, but why are you switching from os global (`$::os`) to os local (`$os`) in your `site.pp`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt . $::os and $os is in my manifest the same toplevel variable os. I have no localscope variables in this example. Yes you are wright the methode "is_hash" is from puppetlabs-stdlib. Since facter 2.0 facter can handle structured facts see here https://docs.puppet.com/facter/2.2/fact_overview.html#writing-structured-facts.  And in my problem if i deactivate the puppetdb all is fine :(. os will be identified as a hash.

Comment: If i simple try this:   `if $os['family'] == 'windows' { notify {'windows':}}` i get the same error like described above ->  os is not a hash or Array when accesssing it with family.

Comment: OK I figured it out. Answering now.